# TSQL using an IF or CASE to generate an IN list

Tags: sql, if-statement

I've got a stored procedure on SQL Server 2008R2 which I'd like to change. The SPROC takes a parameter (one of many) which is a ClientID. What I'd like to achieve is something like this:

```
SELECT <lots of stuff> FROM TABLES
<lots of joins>
WHERE
<a few where/and clauses>
AND -- important bit here!
( 
 IF @ClientID=0 THEN ClientID IN (sub select to get a list of appropriate client ids)
 ELSE -- ClientID param is not 0 and therefore we passed in a single, specified ClientID
 ClientID=@ClientID
)
```

I realise the above is a long way from valid SQL, but essentially I hope it illustrates the problem. Basically, a parameter to the SPROC which, if 0 will trigger some sql to get a list of IDs to look up from (basically an "IN" statement), and if the value is greater than 0, then it's a specific ID to look up on (so a simple where clause filtering on a single specified value).

Since it's an SPROC, it's not a problem to do some pre-code/sql to get the list of multiple ClientIDs (if applicable). It doesn't have to be in a single statement.

Anybody got any ideas on the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: it rather depends on what `sub select to get a list of appropriate client ids` is but, you can do an `IN` on a sub query. Is it possible that `0` is a valid `[ClientId]`?

Comment: Sorry, is should have made it clear, 0 is NOT a valid ClientID

Comment: @Dimt 's answer should work well then.

Comment: Spot on. Dimt/Jodrell/Kiran Hedge, absolutely perfect (subject to a bit more testing) :) Thank you so much! Very much appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to properly nest your where clauses like, below:

```
WHERE
...
AND
(
        @ClientID = 0 AND [ClientID] IN <sub select to get appropriate ids>
    OR
        [ClientID] = @ClientID
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following combination

```
.
.
.
AND
(
    ((@ClientID=0 AND ClientID IN (sub select to get a list of appropriate client ids))
       OR
    (@ClientID<>0 AND ClientID=@ClientID))

)
```